# How do you dynamically parse, read, and append to JSON with multiple sub arrays

Tags: c#, json, parsing, dynamic, dynamically-generated

After a bunch of research I haven't been able to find any good ways to read a json file, store their values, then append a new object/array to it.
The JSON looks like

```
    {
"Skywars": [
  {
    "Solo Normal": [
      {
        "000001": [
          {
            "Kills": 213,
            "Deaths": 117
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Solo Insane": [
      {
        "000001": [
          {
            "Kills": 10790,
            "Deaths": 7184
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
],"Bedwars": [
  {
    "Solo": [
      {
        "000001": [
          {
            "Kills": 0,
            "Deaths": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "Duos": [
      {
        "000001": [
          {
            "Kills": 0,
            "Deaths": 0
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
```

As an example, i am intending for it to go "Skywars.Solo Normal", "Skywars.Solo Insane", "Bedwars.Solo", "Bedwars.Duos" then append "000002" with new kills and deaths values.
For some reason, even after hours of searching, I can't find out how to read the kills and deaths (I've gotten close, using `public Skywars[] Skywars { get;set; }`. Problem is most of the examples are using JSON files that look like `{"user":[{"id":1,"logins":0}]}` with very little arrays & sub arrays.

To anyone who is kind enough to answer, please don't spoonfeed me code, explain how it would be done (would I need to create my own parser, etc), or if there are already any posts/links that answer my question (even though I failed to find how).

Notes -

- "000001" and "000002" will be dynamic, so each time you start the program those values will be different. I just want to append after the last instance of stats saved.

Also sorry, I am still learning C# but know most of the basics and some more complex concepts, I've just never been good at storing data and using JSON. If you need anything to help else just add a comment and I'll add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see Json.NET's [Modifying JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm).

> This sample loads JSON, modifies JObject and JArray instances and then writes the JSON back out again.
>
> ## Sample
>
> ```
> string json = @"{
>  'channel': {
>    'title': 'Star Wars',
>    'link': 'http://www.starwars.com',
>    'description': 'Star Wars blog.',
>    'obsolete': 'Obsolete value',
>    'item': []
>  }
> }";
>
> JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);
>
> JObject channel = (JObject)rss["channel"];
>
> channel["title"] = ((string)channel["title"]).ToUpper();
> channel["description"] = ((string)channel["description"]).ToUpper();
>
> channel.Property("obsolete").Remove();
>
> channel.Property("description").AddAfterSelf(new JProperty("new", "New value"));
>
> JArray item = (JArray)channel["item"];
> item.Add("Item 1");
> item.Add("Item 2");
>
> Console.WriteLine(rss.ToString());
> // {
> //   "channel": {
> //     "title": "STAR WARS",
> //     "link": "http://www.starwars.com",
> //     "description": "STAR WARS BLOG.",
> //     "new": "New value",
> //     "item": [
> //       "Item 1",
> //       "Item 2"
> //     ]
> //   }
> // }
> ```